# PHP/MySQL, sending me back to signup form

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to create a message form for an online portfolio, first working with a local database and then switching it later. When I hit "submit" button, it takes back to the signup form on the index.php file. I've based the code off of an earlier practice, obviously I'm not doing something right, but I'm still beginner to PHP (plus, useless college classes get into the way of my being to focus solely on coding, which has.....significantly played a role in me not being able to focus solely on coding). It's taking me back to the signup form at the index page, which indicates I am doing something wrong.

**Form from index.php:**

```
<form action="includes/process.php" method="POST">
     <p>First Name:</p>
    <input type="text" id="first" name="first"> <p>Last Name:</p>
  <input type="text" id="last" name="last">       
  <br>
  <p>E-mail:</p>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"> <br>
  <p>Message:</p>
     <textarea id="message" name="message" size="10000" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

**Code from the includes/db.php**

```
<?php 

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "portfoliomessages";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
```

**Code for includes/process.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include_once 'db.php';


$first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["first"]);
$last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["last"]);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"]);
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["message"]);
//error handlers
//Check for empty fields

if( empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email)|| empty($message) )  {
    header("Location: ../index.php?index=empty");
    exit();
} else {
    //check if input characters are valid
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", 
 $last) ) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?index=invalid");
        exit();
    } else {
        //check if email is valid
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?index=email");
        exit();
            } else {
                //Insert message into database
                $sql = "INSERT INTO newmessagesthirdattempt (first, last, 
  message, email) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$message', '$email);";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                header("Location: ../success.php");
                exit();
            }
        }

    }

} else {
header("Location: ../index.php");
exit();
}
```

Comment: You can easily debug it with echo commands to your conditions. Also can you share POST information with us ?

Comment: you want redirect to success.php ?

Comment: You should look into prepared statements, it will stop problems when people put quotes in the message etc.  It will also stop things like - `'$email)` which is missing a close quote.

Comment: might be `isset($_POST['submit'])` is looking for an input button with `name = "submit"` . Could you try this `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">`

Answer (score -1):

According to the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls) only inputs with name attribute are processed.
Here your submit is lacking the name attribute. That's why `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` is not true.

You could add a name attribute to your submit button or test another input like "first" or "last".

Another way would by to pass an argument to your process file :

```
<form action="includes/process.php?action=something" method="POST">
```

and then :

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='something') {
```

If your process.php file receive a lot of treatments you can easily add a `switch` here.